# How to set the textfield format as decimal while typing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my app i have one text field and when i click on that text field numeric keypad will open.now my question is how to convert that value in decimal format while typing as i have to insert only decimal values and in numeric  keypad dot(.)is not given.so when user type in textfield it automatically convert that value into decimal format.

> Suppose if user type **5078** it will show **50.78** format while typing.

Comment: is decimal position fixed that it will come before or after some digits

Comment: what will hapeen if it is 5 or 50 or 5000078 .

Comment: what if he just types `8` or `78`?

Comment: ya up to two decimal place is fixed.if user type 5 it will display 0.05 and for 5000078 it display 50000.78

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply multiply the number by "*0.01*" (for two decimal places) and use the string format "*%.2lf*". Write the following code in *`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:withString:`* method.

```
NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
double number = [text intValue] * 0.01;
textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lf", number];
return NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
    replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    double currentValue = [textField.text doubleValue];
    double cents = round(currentValue * 100.0f);

    if ([string length]) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (isnumber(c)) {
                cents *= 10;
                cents += c - '0'; 
            }            
        }
    } else {
        // back Space
        cents = floor(cents / 10);
    }

    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", cents / 100.0f];
     if(cents==0)
    {
        textField.text=@"";
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
    }
```

Comment: This solves the problem. But you can still do it by a simple multiplication and a string format!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks userar, it works fine for me.  Im my case i need to format the decimal like a currency localized format when finish the editing.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

      NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
      formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

      // im my case i need specify the currency code, 
      // but could have got it from the system.
      formatter.currencyCode = @"BRL";

      NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = 
            [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:textField.text];

     // keeping the decimal value for submit to server.
     self.decimalValue = decimalNumber;

     // formatting to currency string.
     NSString * currencyString = [formatter stringFromNumber:decimalNumber];
     textField.text = currencyString;
```

}