# How to set UITextField for decimal values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield, decimal

I have a ManageItemVC that has a bunch of `UITextField`s, and one is for price. I've put a placeholder as `0.00`, and the user can use the decimal keyboard to input. I'd like to always keep it in a `#.##` state, as in, no matter how big the number is, it should always have two decimal places (for cents). If the user taps the `.` in the keyboard (decimal point), I don't want it to add that, because I already have that decimal point in my text field.

I tried implementing the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441315/how-to-set-the-textfield-format-as-decimal-while-typing), in the accepted answer, and I know that's a delegate method that `UITextFieldDelegate` provides, but where do I place this method? Should I subclass `UITextField`, put that method in there and then set it as the class of that price textfield I have? Or should I just place it in my `ManageItemVC`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to subclass the UITextField,

1) delegate,

```
@interface  ManageItemVC ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

2) set **self** as the textfield's delegate,

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: That's it, I had forgotten to forget to set the delegate! Thanks!